# Execute a remote command on a Mac from Windows

Tags: windows, ssh, mac, batch

What's the easiest way to execute a single command on a Mac from a remote Windows machine, via batch?

I would like something that works **without** a preset configuration (like SSH credentials) on either machines, as I need to apply this on several Win/Mac pairs (yes, I know it's less secure, but it's not relevant to my needs).

The macs all have a common user/password (in fact, they are on the same domain), and I want to automate this as painlessly as possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Anything like this, whether it's to a Mac or a Linux machine I use WinSCP, as it has good scripting support and is very easy to use. Just set up public keys for SSH to eliminate the password prompt.

**Edit**

Here's a batch file using PuTTY if you don't mind the password issue.

```
@echo off
echo command1; command2; commandn; exit>tmp_file
putty -ssh user@taget_machine -pw password -m tmp_file
```

Comment: I would like something that doesn't force me to setup SSH public keys, because i need to set them up from/to multiple computers.

Comment: You don't have to but then you have the problem of having to enter the password.

Comment: I would like a way to automate entering the password. I don't mind storing the user/pass in the batch script.

Comment: @ripper234, see the edit to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose on the windows server you could use putty/plink to connect to the mac via SSH (assuming that ssh is open and running).

First use putty to create a shared key on the windows server and you'll put that on the mac... probably authorized_keys file.  Don't set a password on the key.

Then, you could use plink to login and run a command using that key.

Check out: http://tartarus.org/~simon/putty-snapshots/htmldoc/Chapter7.html#plink-usage-batch
"7.2.2 Using Plink for automated connections"

Putty is available here:
 http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/

Comment: I would like something that doesn't force me to setup SSH public keys, because i need to set them up from/to multiple computers.